# How to escape < in querystring

Tags: soql, batch, query

I have a batch class with a query string in which I want to limit the query to records last modified before a datetime, but the '<' char seems to need escaping and I can't find any documentation to tell me how.  I have a dim and distant memory of using & lt; but that doesn't seem to work either.

Help!

eg
    global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

```
    String todaysDate = string.valueof(date.today());
    string query = 'Select Id, Name, StageName, CloseDate FROM Opportunity'
        + 'where LastModifiedDate < 2013-07-23T12:00:00.000Z';


    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
```

gives me a run time error on the '<' and if I use & lt; in its place.

Comment: You don't ordinarily use &lt; in Apex Code (you're thinking of JavaScript/HTML). When in doubt for situations like this, always try a System.debug (e.g. `System.debug(query)`), which will usually help outline the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the error message is misleading.  You're missing a space between 'Opportunity' and 'where'.